# Form unable to center and max width

Tags: html, css, django

I have a form that I would like to center in a div, but also apply a max-width

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```html
  <div class="site-section mb-5">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="form-register">
       <form method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
               <legend>Join Today</legend>
               {{ form|crispy }}
               <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
       </form>
     </div>
      <p class="p-center">Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
          </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.form-register {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However if I switch the `width` and `max-width` between the two CSS classes, I get either of the following results:

[image: whole-page]

or

[image: left-align]

Comment: Don't use `display: inline` if you want to adjust block-level properties. Use `display: block`, you'll probably have more luck achieving what you want.

Comment: That's it! Gonna read up on the different display types now.